# How can es-lint be configured to warn/error if useState is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I've not been able to find a rule, but is it possible to throw a warning or an error if someone attempts to reach for `useState` instead of the state provider?

I'm hoping I don't need to reach for a custom rule, but can work through that if there isn't an existing one out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax)

All you need to do is play around with [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/). I have done it for you and you need to add this to your `.eslintrc` file in `rules` section.

In the example below depending upon your need you can either throw it as an `error` or `warn`.

```
"no-restricted-syntax": [
     "error",
     {
         "selector": "CallExpression[callee.name='useState']",
         "message": "Please use state provider instead."
     }
],
```