# ESLint disable default export

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

So far I've been unable to figure out a ready to use solution for throwing an error if something does a default export.

We internally have the standard to only do named exports, but I'd like the linter to ensure it doesn't happen.

Is there a way to accomplish this short of writing a custom rule?

EDIT: I'm assuming, but could very easily be wrong, that I could use the `no-restricted-syntax` rule like I was pointed to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67186703/how-can-es-lint-be-configured-to-warn-error-if-usestate-is-used). I just didn't want to reach for that if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would be best to use `eslint-plugin-import` to enforce import and export rules. It has a lovely rule to prevent default exports [`import/no-default-export`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/no-default-export.md).

```sh
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-import
```

**`.eslintrc`**

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    "import"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "import/no-default-export": "error"
  }
}
```